# Make a JavaScript Function Variable Optional and Execute code if it is missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple JavaScript/jQuery code below that I am building that will update a circle graph style CSS chart for my Project Management application.

If you look at the Function below you can see I have added a variable that gets passed into the function named `percent`.  This will allow me to have the graph update by calling the function and passing the desired Percent number into the function.

On line 4 you can see I have this other code that sets the `percent` variable by reading a Data Attribute on a DIV.
`var percent = parseInt($ppc.data('percent'));`

My goal is to have the functionality of both of these!

So basically  would like for the Function `updateProjectPercentageGraph(percent)` Percent variable to be optional.

**A)**
So if the Function is called like this...
`updateProjectPercentageGraph(percent)` then it will use the `Percent` value that is passed into the function.

**&**

**B)**
When the Function is called like this...
`updateProjectPercentageGraph()` with NO Percent variable/value passed into the Function...then the `Percent` value will come from this code inside the Function... `var percent = parseInt($ppc.data('percent'));` instead.

Can someone show me how I can achieve this with JavaScript/jQuery?

It is super easy with PHP but with JavaScript I am not sure how to do this or if it is even possible the way I described?

**The JavaScript Code for Function `updateProjectPercentageGraph(percent)`...**

```
// Update Project DetailView Project Percentage Graph
function updateProjectPercentageGraph(percent){
  var $ppc = $('.progress-pie-chart'),
    //percent = parseInt($ppc.data('percent')),
    deg = 360*percent/100;
  if (percent > 50) {
    $ppc.addClass('gt-50');
  }
  $('.ppc-progress-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
  $('.ppc-percents span').html(percent+'%');
};
```

**What the HTML/CSS Will look like when the JavaScript Function runs...**
[image]

**An example of my desired functionality shown in PHP.  I need this functionality but in JavaScript...**

```
// Update Project DetailView Project Percentage Graph
function updateProjectPercentageGraph($percent = ''){
    if(isset($percent) && $percent != ''){
        // $percent is set in the Function constructor/variable
    }else{
        // $percent is NOT SET, so we need to get or build it;s value from elsewhere!
    }
};
```

Comment: `percent = precent || parseInt($ppc.data('percent'));`

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't currently have any well supported syntactic sugar for this (but see [ECMAScript 6](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation)), but all arguments are optional and default to `undefined`.

```
function updateProjectPercentageGraph(percent) {
    if (typeof percent === "undefined") {
        percent = "some default value";
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on what browsers one needs to support, firefox supports named function parameters. Only one to do so, so far.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, if there is a parameter and the user omits it, it will be `undefined`.  You can check for that and then perform your magic appropriately:

```
function someFunc(someParam) {
  if (typeof someParam === 'undefined') {
    // User did not supply their parameter.
    return;
  }

  // If it gets here, we have a valid someParam to use for whatever.
}

// Call the function without supplying the parameter and it will be undefined.
someFunc();
```